# TTTAttributedLabel with large amounts of text which requires scrolling

Tags: ios, tttattributedlabel

I am using the TTTAttributedLabel library to build links in a block of text.  I believe TTTAttributedLabel uses UILabel (not easily scrollable) as a base class instead of UITextView which is scrollable.  This text view can contain a relatively large amount of text which means that it will need to scroll in some cases.  I can't find any help on the library to explain how to configure the TTTAttributedLabel to allow scrolling.

Answer (score 2):

You should set the same code below:

```
yourTTTAttributedLabel.extendsLinkTouchArea = NO;
```

It is the best solution. I hope useful.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the TTTAttributedLabel to a UIScrollView.  As a bonus, you can add a constraint to the TTTAttributedLabel to match widths with its parent so it will only scroll vertically.